# Twitter Streaming API: limitation notice

Tags: twitter, notifications, twitter-streaming-api

What does it mean

> Got track limitation notice: INT

(where `INT` is a number) when streaming from the Twitter API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you have missed N tweets in total since the connections was opened.

see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#authentication-rate-limiting

I think this is a quite good explanation: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11486